# Get Invoice id when create invoice

Tags: event-observer, invoice, magento2.3.2

Magento version is 2.3.2
I use the `sales_order_invoice_register` event to send the invoice id to the third party API when create the invoice.
 My code in the observer is :

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$orderId = $invoice->getOrderId();`
$invoiceNumber = $invoice->getIncrementId();
```

I Got the order id but Invoice id I got blank.
Does anyone have an idea how to get invoice id?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
$invoice_id = $invoice->getData('increment_id');
```

I hope its work for you.

Comment: Please check before post the answer. It's not working.

Comment: you want invoice id ?

Comment: Yes, invoice id.

Comment: than try with $invoice->getData();

Comment: I tried that but Fatal error:  Out of memory

Comment: try with - $invoice->getData('increment_id'); , its working for my side.

Comment: I tried that also not working.

Comment: so please increase memory limit than check with $invoice->getData();

Comment: also try this one - $invoice->getId()

Comment: I tried all that. That's why ask to please test in Magento 2.3.2 and then post the answer.

Comment: Hi @KrunalPandya, did you manage to get the invoice number after all? I'm facing the same issue and I don't know why the invoice id is empty.

Comment: @PauGNU I did something else for this but you can try with different event may be its work.